# Ubuntu on H77 chipset motherboard

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have used Ubuntu for 1 - 2 years. I am now running Ubuntu 11.04 (32 bit) on a 2007 system with "core-2-due" CPU, Intel P35 chipset motherboard with 2GB memory and nVidia GeForce 8500GT display card. I have fine-tuned my Ubuntu system so that it works smoothly with my favorite applications.

However, I am planning to buy a new computer with the following config :

```
Intel i5 2400,  
Intel H77 chipset motherboard (ASUS P8H77-M) with 8GB ram (with SATA III and USB 3.0),
500/1T GB SATA harddisk (planning only, not yet choose the model. Perhaps WD),
nVidia GeForce GT 630 display card,
```

I want to know that could my fine-tuned 32 bit Ubuntu 11.04 system be just moved to the harddisk of my new i5 2400 H77 chipset computer and it would boot up the new computer ? i.e. Could my fine-tuned Ubuntu recognizes the i5 2400, H77 chipset, SATA III, USB 3.0 etc ? If not, could I add some drivers / kernel modules to my Ubuntu system to make it work with my new computer ? (I have experience in moving Ubuntu system from one harddisk to another harddisk, but with the same CPU and motherboard.)

Moreover, if my attempt to move my existing Ubuntu 11.04 system to the new computer fails, would the most current Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit) system be able to be installed to my new computer with the mentioned config ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Ubuntu by default comes with all driver kernel modules either built into the kernel or autoloadable.  Can you explain what fine tuning you have done to Ubuntu to make it work with your hardware?

Comment: I have used an ext2 /boot partition with a LVM2 root partition, the initrd image in /boot has been modified so that it could load a LVM2 partition. Moreover, my original 2007 motherboard uses the old SATA interface and USB 2.0 interface, and uses the GeForce 8500GT display card.

Comment: Ok, but have you made any specific changes to ubuntu to support your hardware, or is it all standard out of the box ubuntu?

Comment: In fact, in my original motherboard, I used the IDE emulation mode of the SATA (set in BIOS) so that Ubuntu treat my harddisks as IDE disks and I could install the Ubuntu system on them. However, for the planning H77 chipset motherboard, I don't know whether this mode exists or not and whether my current fine-tuned Ubuntu system could see the new SATA 3.0 drive. I just state here for anyone who has this experience to share with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have made no changes to your Ubuntu installation to support your specific hardware, but are using standard Ubuntu, then moving your hard disk to a new machine should "just work".

The best way to test this is to get a live CD for the version you have installed on your existing machine and attempt to boot it on the new hardware.

If it comes up ok, and you can see any hard disks already in the system (set the SATA mode to IDE in the bios of the new system in the same way you have the current one), then you can expect that transferring the hard disk will work.

If you have any problems, then upgrading your ubuntu installation on the current system to a newer release would be best, then do the transfer.

Comment: After reading your suggestion and some googling, it seems that no one has said Ubuntu has trouble with the new SATA 3 and USB 3 interface. I think the H77 chipset motherboard is worth a try. Thanks for your answer.